# How to create an excel file with multiple sheets using Julia?

Tags: excel, julia, xlsx

I'm programing in **Julia** and trying to create an excel file with multiple sheets for saving some data. The problem is that the function **XLSX.openxlsx()** only creates excels with one sheet.
I'm trying to run the following code.

```
XLSX.openxlsx("test_file.xlsx", mode="w") do xf
    sheet = xf[1]
    XLSX.rename!("first")
    sheet["A1"] = "A"
    sheet = xf[2]
    XLSX.rename!("second")
    sheet["A1"] = "B"
    sheet = xf[3]
    XLSX.rename!("third")
    sheet["A1"] = "C"
end
```

Does anyone know how to create excel files with multiple sheets? or maybe create new sheets in an existing file?

Answer (score 2):

[XLSX.addsheet!](https://felipenoris.github.io/XLSX.jl/dev/api/#XLSX.addsheet!) is what you're looking for.

```
XLSX.openxlsx("test_file.xlsx", mode="w") do xf
    XLSX.rename!(xf[1], "first")

    for sheetname in ["second", "third", "fourth"]
      XLSX.addsheet!(xf, sheetname)
    end

    xf[1]["A1"] = "A"
    xf[2]["A1"] = "B"
    xf[3]["A1"] = "C"

    # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`writetable` accepts several worksheets as keyword arguments. Hence, I usually use a one-liner to export all data frames to an Excel file. I also definitely recommend to create a `DataFrame`, manipulate it and finally save to Excel as the `DataFrames` API is obviously more convenient than `XLSX` API for data manipulation.

See the code below:

```
using DataFrames, XLSX
df1 = DataFrame(a=1:5, b=string.("Hello",1:5), c=6.5:10.5)
df2 = DataFrame(a=1:5, d=[11,22,33,missing,missing] )

XLSX.writetable("dfs.xlsx", overwrite=true, 
    WORKSHEET_A=(collect(DataFrames.eachcol(df1)), DataFrames.names(df1)),
    WORKSHEET_B=(collect(DataFrames.eachcol(df2)), DataFrames.names(df2)),
    #add more data frames when needed   
)
```

[image]